# play videos side by side MELT

Tags: mlt

I am having issues in playing videos side by side. Can someone help me?
I am observing for my MELT sequence 1 video is scaled properly, but other is cropped.

Please suggest solution. Here is my melt command.

melt A_David_Beckham.mp4 in=0 out=650 \
-track -blank 49 C_KindleTouch.mp4 in=0 out=650 \
-transition composite start=0/0:960x1080 end=0/0:960x1080 distort=1 a_track=1 b_track=0 \
-transition composite start=960/0:960x1080 end=960/0:960x1080 distort=1 a_track=0 b_track=1 \
-transition mix:-1 in=50 out=650 a_track=0 b_track=1

A_Backham is scaled properly starting 50th frame, but C_KindleTouch.mp4 is cropped. 
Both videos are HD videos and having length > 650 frames.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a Blank track running through in order to achieve this feat.

Here is MELT command to play 2 videos below in parallel audio of 2nd video will play. Switch tracks in order to switch audio.

```
melt colour:black out=650 \
-track A_David_Beckham.mp4 in=0 out=650 \
-track C_KindleTouch.mp4 in=0 out=650 \
-transition composite start=0/0:960x1080 end=0/0:960x1080 distort=1 a_track=0 b_track=1 \
-transition composite start=960/0:960x1080 end=960/0:960x1080 distort=1 a_track=0 b_track=2
```

In case you need to implement a Credit Squeeze.. Here is a way...
(Movie channels typically has requirement to squeeze In End Credits on Left and Start Playing next movie on right)

```
time melt colour:black out=599 \
-track C_KindleTouch.mp4 in=0 out=299 C_KindleTouch.mp4 in=300 out=349 -attach volume:0.1 C_KindleTouch.mp4 in=350 out=599 \
-track -blank 49 B_Samsung.mp4 in=0 out=599 \
-transition composite start=0/0:1920x1080 end=0/0:960x1080 distort=1 a_track=0 b_track=1 in=50 out=99 \
-transition composite start=1920/0:960x1080 end=960/0:960x1080 distort=1 a_track=0 b_track=2 in=50 out=99 \
-transition mix:-1 in=50 out=99 a_track=0 b_track=2 \
-transition composite start=0/0:960x1080 end=0/0:960x1080 distort=1 a_track=0 b_track=1 in=100 out=299 \
-transition composite start=960/0:960x1080 end=960/0:960x1080 distort=1 a_track=0 b_track=2 in=100 out=299 \
-transition composite start=0/0:960x1080 end=-960/0:960x1080 distort=1 a_track=0 b_track=1 in=300 out=349 \
-transition composite start=960/0:960x1080 end=0/0:1920x1080 distort=1 a_track=0 b_track=2 in=300 out=349 \
-transition mix:-1 in=300 out=349 a_track=0 b_track=2 \
-consumer avformat:output-squeeze_nd_back_final_v6.ts vcodec=nvenc_h264 vb=5000k acodec=aac ab=256k mlt_image_format=yuv420p
```

This is how effect is working

1. Play Black or Blank screen on Track 0, Play Video 1  (End Credits part) on Track 1 , play video 2 on track 2
2. Squeeze in Video 1 from full screen to left half as you bring in Video 2 in right half, mix it
3. Play Both videos in parallel for some duration
4. Squeeze Out Video1 and Expand Video 2 to full screen

Comment: This looks good except that usage of start/end is discouraged in favor of [geometry](http://www.mltframework.org/bin/view/MLT/TransitionComposite#geometry).
Then, if you want to [animate](http://www.mltframework.org/bin/view/MLT/PropertyAnimation) it you simply supply a semi-colon delimited value.